# Perl threads get iterations speed

Tags: multithreading, perl, profiling

I have some code:

```
for my $t (1..$threads) {
  push @threads, threads->create(\&action_, $t);
}
for my $t (@threads) {
  $t->join();
}

sub action_ {
  while (@sites) {
    my $url = shift @sites;
    for my $data1 (@data) {
      for my $data2 (@data2) {
        something($url, $data1, $data2);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to get speed(number of calls method "something") per second(or minute)?
Thanks.

Comment: Ever tried to use Devel::NYTProf? I'm not sure if it handles threads appropriately, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to do it yourself quickly, a gross estimate can be obtained like so:

```
use List::Util qw(sum);
use feature qw(say);
...

my $t0 = time();  # See also Time::HiRes
threads->create(\&action_) for 1 .. $nthreads;
my $nsomething = sum map { $_->join } threads->list();
my $elapsed = time() - $t0;

say "Among $nthreads threads we called something() ",
    ($nsomething/$elapsed),
    " times per second";

sub action_ {
  my $n;
  while (...) { ... something(); $n++; ... }
  return $n;
}
```

If that's not fine enough, you might have each call to `something()` push the time it was invoked on to a `threads::shared::share()`d array — or in a thread-local array that you collect after the join(), or printed to a mutex-protected filehandle or whatever.  Then you can do whatever you like with the time series you've generated.

Comment: Open a separate question on SO detailing how and how often you'd like to display the data, how you're going to collect it from the running program and what you've already tried.

Comment: In other words it is just brute force and i want to know pps(password per second)

Answer (score 2):

Perl has a number of benchmarking modules in CPAN.  Take a look at: http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html

This explains it well; basically the code you want to benchmark is wrapped up in a subroutine and you're free to count or compare different routines.

The method I use most commonly is under the heading 'Methods' and 'New'.

Comment: Not germane.  The OP wants to profile, not benchmark.  He wants performance numbers for actual calls *in situ*.